# Test class instance appears in my model?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know how to explain it, it is really weird.

I'm testing some methods of a class, just use XCTest, I didn't use any other test framework in this test case.

At the first time I convert a dictionary to a model, and set it to a local variable, it works well.

But at the second time(just after first time), it went wrong. I have traced the stack, and found just before local variable being set with the new converted model, everything is **correct**, the return value of `initWithDict` is correct. But when the return value is set to local variable, something weird appears.

The pointer of the local variable is not the pointer of return value. And every property in model messed up. Even one property is set to a **XXXXTests** class instance. It should be my **test class**, how I can get it and set it to model???

[image: first time]

---

[image: second time]

**EDIT**

```
-(void)testFindSubDictionaryWithDictionary{
    NSMutableDictionary* dict=[ToolMethod recursivelyMutateArrayOrDictionary:_miniComponentTreeData];
    ComponentTreeDataManager* componentTreeDataManager=[ComponentTreeDataManager manager];
    NSMutableDictionary* obj=[componentTreeDataManager findSubDictionaryWithDictionary:dict InvertListPath:@"dynamic,a_new" identification:@"triger_xinsui"];
}
```

And I also found that modifying my input dictionary will not affect the result. The *second* time will go wrong, not first not third not fourth, just second.

But if I copy `ComponentTreeDataModel* model=[[ComponentTreeDataModel alloc]initWithDict:obj];`, and make something like:

```
ComponentTreeDataModel* model=[[ComponentTreeDataModel alloc]initWithDict:obj];
ComponentTreeDataModel* model1=[[ComponentTreeDataModel alloc]initWithDict:obj];
ComponentTreeDataModel* model2=[[ComponentTreeDataModel alloc]initWithDict:obj];
ComponentTreeDataModel* model3=[[ComponentTreeDataModel alloc]initWithDict:obj];
```

Then, all of those duplicated models are right, everytime.

Anyone can help me, and explain what it is???

Comment: Images are quite discouraged on SO. Can you show code of your test method? Also it seems that some big parts of the code on the images got whitened out.

Comment: Updated, whitened out code is an **if statement** and never reached. @Losiowaty

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Xcode variable inspector which shows me the wrong data.

After I clean up the project, it seems correct now.

Xcode always wastes my time, sigh.

This is a complaint, not an answer.